# I cannot use any feature of anaconda despite uninstalling and reinstalling

Tags: anaconda, conda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PsT5.png)It would be great if someone could help me.  I have uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda and miniconda and nothing works.  Everything installs and shows up in the start menu, but when I click on navigator or Jupyter or spider, the command window flashed on for a second and nothing happens.

This is pretty spooky that no one else seems to have this problem.  I even tried to uninstall python because I got a error that said a python38.dll was interfering with something or other, but guess what, python doesn't show up in my apps list so how am I supposed to delete it?  Neverthless, if I type in "python" into the command window, sure enough, the three arrows show up and I can print 'hello world,
 so wtf?

Please help,

Paul

Comment: Python running from  the command prompt w/o activating conda is not standard behaviour. So why did you change default settings during Anaconda setup?

Comment: Here's a shot of my anaconda command line.  Navigator, Spyder, Jupyter notebook shows up on my start page, but when i click them, Zero.  Nothing happens, it's a brick.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions, and read the documentation for Conda? _I have uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda and miniconda and nothing works._ There are likely traces remaining of multiple installations. It sounds like a bit of a mess, in these kinds of situations your best bet is usually to remove Anaconda/Miniconda/Coda/whatever else **completely**, and start over.

Comment: @Peter _Python running from the command prompt w/o activating conda is not standard behaviour. So why did you change default settings during Anaconda setup?_ Doesn't Conda override the default Python installation? I'm not sure I'm remembering things correctly though, I'll double check.